# Why does Spring Security always respond with 403 Forbidden on all form Posts?

Tags: java, spring-security

I'm putting together a simple website using spring-boot (v2.1.3) and spring-mvc.  It was working well until I added spring-security by including the spring-boot-starter-security dependency and adding an implementation of WebMvcConfigurer.  Everything worked fine, including the default login and logout views, but all other forms respond with 403-Forbidden on POST's.

The bulk of the guidance I've seen involves csrf protection.  Ultimately, you want to include csrf tokens in your form, but the simplest advice is to disable csrf protection completely (http.csrf.disable()).  Adding that to the security configuration had no effect.

Here is my WebMvcConfigurer implementation...

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
 public class WebSecurityConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                    .formLogin()
                .and()
                    .httpBasic()
                .and()
                    .csrf().disable();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() throws Exception {
        InMemoryUserDetailsManager manager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();

        manager.createUser(User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username("user")
                .password("password")
                .roles("USER")
                .build());

        return manager;
    }
 }
```

Looking for any assistance on basic spring security configuration as it relates to form POST's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement WebSecurityConfigurer instead of WebMvcConfigurer

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurer {
}
```

Comment: Yup, that's it.  Although technically it's: `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter'.  There's a discussion to fix the documentation [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/6809).  Thanks.